# Do I need to release COM Object if only pass it an instance of another COM object

Tags: c#, memory-management, com

Let's say I have the following scenario:

```
ComObjectClass firstCOMObject = new ComObjectClass();
ComObjectClass secondCOMObject = firstCOMObject;
```

Of course I have to release the `firstCOMObject` like this:

```
Marshal.FinalReleaseCOMObject(firstCOMObject);
```

But do I need to release secondCOMObject?
Can you verify your answers with MSDN or another article link?

Comment: This will only make your code crash.  There is still only one object, your code just has two references to it.  Review your favorite C# language book about reference types.

Comment: What about COM Callable Wrapper? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx

Comment: You should not use `FinalReleaseCOMObject`, but rather clear the references you are holding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.finalreleasecomobject.aspx

> The FinalReleaseComObject method releases the managed reference to a
>   COM object. Calling this method is equivalent to calling the
>   ReleaseComObject method in a loop until it returns 0 (zero).

So, no.

Comment: What about COM Callable Wrapper? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx

Comment: @Dor, that's the other way (calling .NET code wrapped with a COM interface), and is handled with normal COM reference counting: "Unlike the .NET client it wraps, the CCW is reference-counted in traditional COM fashion. When the reference count on the CCW reaches zero, the wrapper releases its reference on the managed object. A managed object with no remaining references is collected during the next garbage-collection cycle."  They are opposite directions of wrapping to your original question.